# Reference: A rigorous mathematical approach to Deep Learning

Tags: reference-request, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

I am searching for any reference that has a mathematical (and/or theoretical physics) rigorious approach to key principles in deep learning.

While most books that I have came across with are heavily focused on computational simulation and designing artificial neural networks, many concepts of deep learning revolve around linear algebra, multivariable calculus, informal probability theory, and a special interest in neural networks and I would hope someone can recommend a reference that tackles deep learning rigorously

Comment: You may find [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202442/deep-learning-deep-neural-nets-for-mathematician) has some interesting resources.

Comment: [This textbook](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) is one of the better options.

Comment: But the literature sometimes has things that the textbooks do not. You're physics background might go nicely with [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.13478).

Comment: Lecture Notes for Machine Learning Theory (CS$229$M/STATS$214$) by Dr. Tengyu Ma were posted online on June 26 of this year. Refer this website http://web.stanford.edu/class/stats214/

Answer (score 1):

If you have adequate background, these two physicists have published a book on [The Principles of Deep Learning Theory](https://deeplearningtheory.com/). A draft version is freely available as well.